# PostgreSQL - Comparison operator with character varying - Exclude values

Tags: postgresql

I want to query a PostgreSQL table with comparison operators. This table have two character varying columns.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test
(
    scope character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    project_code character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

**Values**

```
INSERT INTO test.test(scope, project_code) VALUES (NULL, 'AA');
INSERT INTO test.test(scope, project_code) VALUES ('A', 'AA');
```

When I wan't to query values with a `project_code = 'AA'` and a `scope = 'A'`, I write:

```
SELECT * FROM test.test WHERE project_code LIKE 'AA' AND scope LIKE 'A';
```

It returns me one row, result is ok.

But when I try to query values with a `project_code = 'AA'` and `scope` with any other values than `'A'`, I write:

```
SELECT * FROM test.test WHERE project_code LIKE 'AA' AND scope NOT LIKE 'A';
```

It doesn't return me any results. But I have a row who match this. How to explain this and how to write this query ?

I try other comparaison operators `<>` and `!=`, same result. I'm using PostgreSQL 13.6.

Comment: LIKE without a wildcard makes no sense `LIKE 'A'` is exactly the same as `= 'A'` and most probably faster as well.

Comment: The `NULL` is causing the problem. Try `scope IS DISTINCT FROM 'A'`. For explanation see [Comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a NULL safe comparison operator. The SQL standard defines the `is not distinct from` operator as the NULL safe version of `<>` and Postgres supports this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM test.test 
WHERE project_code = 'AA' 
  AND scope IS DISTINCT FROM 'A';
```

Comment: Ok Why do you say 'safe comparison' ? [Official documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) says: `<> is the standard SQL notation for “not equal”. != is an alias`, so I don't understand the difference ?

Comment: @GeoGyro: where do I use `<>` in my query? `is distinct from` is the null safe variant of `<>`. Quote from [the page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISON-PRED-TABLE) you linked: "*Not equal, treating null as a comparable value.*"

Comment: I thought `<>` handle `NULL` values. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` in most operations will return `NULL`. For example

```
SELECT NULL LIKE 'A', NULL NOT LIKE 'A'
```

returns (`NULL`, `NULL`). Probably handling the `NULL` case specifically helps:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    test.test 
WHERE
         project_code LIKE 'AA'
    AND  (scope IS NULL OR scope NOT LIKE 'A')
```

The solution offered by @a_horse_with_no_name is more elegant; this solution may be interesting when using "wildcards" in the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
select null like 'a' is true; --return false
select null not like 'a' is true; --return false 
select null like 'a'; --return null
select null not like 'a' ; --return null
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html.

> If pattern does not contain percent signs or underscores, then the
> pattern only represents the string itself; in that case LIKE acts like
> **the equals operator**. An underscore (_) in pattern stands for (matches)
> any single character; a percent sign (%) matches any sequence of zero
> or more characters.